Long-running process with WPF front-end on a Windows IPC fails with "Not enough memory resources are available to process this command"
We are seeing a problem on some machines with a Windows IPC that are running a long-running background (production) process and are using WPF as the GUI technology. Sometimes after running long jobs for over a day, the process all of a sudden fails with the error message "Not enough memory resources are available to process this command".
Sometimes when that has happened, the whole computer is unresponsive. It is not completely dead -- for example, it will still have a progress indicator spinning, so WPF animations are still working. But the process cannot be shut down, no other application can start, not even the performance monitor or the Task manager, the Start menu doesn't come up, pressing Ctrl-Alt-Del to shut down the computer doesn't do anything. The only way out of this is to power-cycle the computer.
When the computer is not completely unresponsive, it is sometimes possible to exit the software. This seems to restore normal functioning of the computer, but when trying to restart the software and start over, the problem will happen again and even sooner (after a few hours as opposed to more than a day).
We have checked, the system is not actually out of memory, and the program's memory footprint is reasonable. None of the heaps have an excessive byte count. Also, exiting the process should clear any memory it uses. Yet running the software seems to mysteriously degrade the operating system's memory, though it is not clear how.
At the time when the error happens, the machine is not doing much. It's mostly working in the background, happily humming along doing its production process. The GUI only does very minor progress indicators of the process (for example, the progress spinner, and a bit of display updating).

.NET Framework Version: 4.7.2
Operating system: Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC
RAM: 8.00 GB
Program Memory Usage: About 200MB

We have the impression that the error message might be misleading, and it's not actual memory that is becoming exhausted, but some other "memory resource" from WPF, .NET, or Windows. Would you have an idea which memory resource the message could refer to?

We are a bit further on that.  The call stack of the exception we are getting provides a clue.
We found that there is a problem (bug) in .NET that brought this about, and then a mistake in our code that triggered it.
This is the call stack:
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Not enough memory resources are available to process this command
    at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.RegisterClassEx(WNDCLASSEX_D wc_d)
    at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper..ctor(Int32 classStyle, Int32 style, Int32 exStyle, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height, String name, IntPtr parent, HwndWrapperHook[] hooks)
    at MS.Win32.MessageOnlyHwndWrapper..ctor()
    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher..ctor()
    at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.get_CurrentDispatcher()
    at System.Windows.Input.CommandManager.RaiseRequerySuggested()
    at <Our Company>.<... more namespaces ....>.Wpf.Commands.GenericCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()

Here is how we trigger this accidentally:
The clue is in the fact that this is happening during a background process.
The background production process we are doing is using a legacy piece of code which creates various different threads (new Thread()) to do its work on.
When a certain part of the process is finished, it calls back with "Here is how far I am". That call happens on whatever thread it was running on when it finished that part of the process.
This call gets to an UI element responsible for machine maintenance, or much rather, its DataContext ("ViewModel"). That is noticing that the process is still running and concluding that you currently can't do machine maintenance (because a production process is running). So, it wants to disable its "Do maintenance" button.
Accidentally, the code forgets to channel the button update back to the main UI thread. Since this is MVVM, it isn't naturally associated with a window, so extra work would be necessary to ensure it runs on the UI thread. That extra work was accidentally forgotten.
Our "button update" code uses an in-house implementation of ICommand that uses CommandManager.RaiseRequerySuggested() to update the button state, because this is recommended as best practice, for example here: RelayCommand Memory leak or in this blog post.
... and this is how we trigger the problem.
What now happens we can inspect in the .NET Framework reference source. What I observe here is also still the same in the current github code of dotnet, at the time of writing this.
Here is how .Net's WPF implementation contributes to the problem:
To requery the command states on the current window context, CommandManager.RaiseRequerySuggested() gets the current dispatcher. Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher looks if there is already a Dispatcher associated with the current thread, and if so, returns that. But remember, we are accidentally on a non-UI thread. So there isn't a Dispatcher yet for this thread, and then it happily goes and creates a new one. (The instance constructors of Dispatcher() are private, probably for good reason.)
The new Dispatcher creates a window for itself. There is a comment that says "Create the message-only window we use to receive messages that tell us to process the queue." The class it creates is a MessageOnlyHwndWrapper, and it wraps that into a SecurityCriticalData<T> and sticks that into a field.
(MessageOnlyHwndWrapper derives from HwndWrapper which implements IDisposable, but Dispatcher does not implement IDisposable. I was taught at a point that a class that owns an IDisposable member must implement IDisposable itself, but that on the side.)
HwndWrapper calls into the Win32 API and uses the Dispose pattern (though its implementation differs from the description in the link in which Dispose(...) methods are overridable). In its constructor, among others, it calls RegisterClassEx (the call that fails in the callstack above).
The Documentation says
"All window classes that an application registers are unregistered when it terminates.
No window classes registered by a DLL are unregistered when the DLL is unloaded. A DLL must explicitly unregister its classes when it is unloaded."
This would imply that HwndWrapper should unregister its window class itself. HwndWrapper does call (well, dispatches to call later) UnregisterClass in its Dispose(bool, bool) implementation (the one that gets called in the main Dispose() and by the finalizer as per the Dispose pattern). It also has a separate method UnregisterClass. The call to UnregisterClass in Dispose() depends on a parameter isHwndBeingDestroyed, which is only true when a WM_NCDESTROY message is posted to the window. There is also a DestroyWindow function which also seems to unregister the class, and is initiated in the Dispose(bool, bool). From code inspection, the code seems to ensure in various different ways that the class is unregistered Dispose().  Have a look at .Net Framework or dotnet core (at the time of writing this).
Yet, what we have observed is that this can't always succeed, because it appears that the available class atoms get eaten up slowly over time.
This is what tripped us up. As it happens, this creates a resource leak in a Windows Atom Table that doesn't have a way to be inspected (as other people have observed, for example https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/issues/9693 or Diagnosing RegisterWindowsMessage leak).
In our case, we only got the problem because for legacy reasons, and because of an oversight, we ended up creating lots of different HwndWrappers on lots of different threads, and so registering more and more windows classes without ever unregistering them. We were able to fix this by making sure we do GUI updates only on the GUI thread. But the ATOM leak of HwndWrapper is way more serious, because lots of classes in .NET's WPF implementation create a HwndWrapper, including some that are public and don't rely on a dispatcher.
==================================================================
The low-down if you want to dig further:
RegisterClassEx returns an ATOM. an ATOM is a two-byte unsigned integer that points to an entry in an Windows Atom table. Dany Crunch recently made an excellent video on Atom tables. Or check out the official documentation on Microsoft Learn.
Atom tables have a fixed number of entries. There are 0x4000 = 16,384 string entries available for strings in any atom table, and when they are all used up, no more can be added. This is why no windows can be created anymore when the Atom table used by RegisterClassEx is full. This also explains why a lot has to happen until this table is full -- like, making thousands of windows, or thousands of threads. In our case, it needed several days of processing to trigger it. But when the corresponding ATOM table is full, it will clearly be fatal for Windows. Processes can still run if they don't need any window, but for the user to interact with the system in any way, even just to shut down Windows, it needs to be possible to create a window. If there is a window around that can be closed, handles will be freed up again, and then at least hopefully the user can be logged out or the system rebooted, but the handles lost by HwndWrapper in WPF will never come back otherwise.
There are public Win32 APIs to work with the global and local atom table (Microsoft Learn / Windows / Apps / Win32 / API / Data Exchange / Winbase.h/).
But unfortunately, the documentation for Atom tables tells us that RegisterClassEx adds an ATOM neither in the global nor the local atom table, but another one, the UserAtomTable, and there is no Win32 API for that. So we cannot even query the system to ask if a certain Window class ATOM has been deleted from its Atom table, and we cannot trace these resource leaks.
==================================================================

Rather than using can execute, you could consider just binding  is enabled of your button to a bool property. Or even don't bind, don't suggest any command requesting but instead check a gating bool before you run code in your command(s).  Or maybe move this long running code out your UI project and into a service

Hi @Andy, all good points. Yes there are many ways to skin a cat; the easiest way was for us to make sure we channel the RaiseCanExecuteChanged call back to the UI thread.
Separating the long-running process out into a service is an excellent suggestion, but is a long-term project, not a quick fix, and currently not feasible.

Apparently  the HwndWrapper, and by implication a call to CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested() or Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher or even new BitmapImage().Freeze(), will not properly unregister its window and leak the window class ATOM resources if the thread on which it is running terminates very quickly, and possibly also in other circumstances.
